# Tensorflow Serving keeps returning the same output

Tags: python, tensorflow, fastapi, tensorflow-serving

So, I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6NI0u_lgNo&t=1826s
and right after the tensorflow serving part I had been testing my fastapi API code which looks like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import requests

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
app = FastAPI()

endpoint = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/plant_model:predict"

CLASS_NAMES = ['Potato___Early_blight',
               'Potato___Late_blight',
               'Potato___healthy',
               'Tomato_Early_blight',
               'Tomato_Late_blight',
               'Tomato_healthy']


@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"


def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image


@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
    image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
    img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

    json_data = {
        "instances": img_batch.tolist()
    }

    response = requests.post(endpoint, json=json_data)
    prediction = np.array(response.json()["predictions"][0])

    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(prediction[0])]
    confidence = np.max(prediction[0])

    return {
        'class': predicted_class,
        'confidence': float(confidence)
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

By the way I'm using Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.

and I'm passing the image of a 255x255 leaf to it. (my model is made to classify different kinds of diseases for different kinds of vegetable leaves)

But, for some reason it always gives me this same false output:

```
    "class": "Potato___Early_blight",
    "confidence": 0.374938548
}
```

I also tried it with another leaf image but it's still the same just with a different confidence:

```
    "class": "Potato___Early_blight",
    "confidence": 1.21042137e-06
```

*I can't post images here because my rank is too low*

and here is the link to the AI google colab notebook I made for the AI:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i2v_RbZ8lI-e0joE-qBxym6_6xF5rR0g?usp=sharing

So, what am I doing wrong? I have checked other answers but they go into the specifics of the code instead of a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue at all to get different confidence for different leaf images. Images are different in each  category and the model detect confidence accordingly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).